# При конвертации из QImage в QPixmap ломается изображение

Tags: python, pyqt5, скриншот, qimage, qpixmap

```
def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
    self.d = QPushButton("sss", self)
    self.d.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100)
    self.label = QLabel(self)
    image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1920, 1080))
    q = ImageQt(image)
    q = QImage(q)
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(q)
    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    print(3)
    self.label.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
```

Comment: Вы хотите сделать скрин выбранного участка экрана?

Comment: Показали бы поломанное изображение :) А так, скриншот можно сделать и через `Qt` покажу пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял и вы хотите сделать скрин выбранного участка экрана, тогда попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PIL import ImageGrab


class SnippingWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SnippingWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.outsideSquareColor = "red"
        self.squareThickness = 2

        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_point = event.pos()
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        r = QtCore.QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        self.hide()
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
        img.save("testImage.png")
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        self.closed.emit()
        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        trans = QtGui.QColor(22, 100, 233)
        r = QtCore.QRectF(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        trans.setAlphaF(0.2)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        outer = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        outer.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()))
        inner = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        inner.addRect(r)
        r_path = outer - inner
        qp.drawPath(r_path)
        qp.setPen(
            QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(self.outsideSquareColor), self.squareThickness)
        )
        trans.setAlphaF(0)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        qp.drawRect(r)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Делать скриншот')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.activateSnipping)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 0)

        self.snipper = SnippingWidget()
        self.snipper.closed.connect(self.on_closed)

    def activateSnipping(self):
        self.snipper.showFullScreen()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.hide()

    def on_closed(self):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("testImage.png")
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.show()
        self.adjustSize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скриншот можно сделать через `Qt`, используя метод `grabWindow` класса `QScreen`, заголовок метода:

- [QPixmap QScreen::grabWindow(WId window, int x = 0, int y = 0, int width = -1, int height = -1)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow)
- Если необходимо получить скриншот определенной области экрана, то в `grabWindow` передавайте необходимые параметры (`x`, `y`, `width`, `height`), по умолчанию, выполняется скриншот всего экрана

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8e4d03f65bff32b4ac0f35840cee7c58f7420893/screenshots/screenshot__using_PyQt5.py#L23)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication([])
img = app.primaryScreen().grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())

label = QLabel()
label.setPixmap(img)
label.show()

app.exec()
```